# What does "Bankroll someone's rage" mean?

Tags: word-usage, idioms

During an episode of The Practice, the context can be understood from the actor's whole line.

> Ellenor: Now, I suppose it is politically incorrect to call cancer victims a bunch of whiners, but let's fess up. No other lawyer would touch this case because it is a case that stinks. Did those power lines give you cancer? My bet is yes. Can we prove it in a court of law? My bet there is a resounding, "No." He took this case not because he was greedy, but because he felt sorry for you. And against all odds, he got you an offer like this, it's a miracle. Close to a million dollars, I am sorry, but that is as good as it's gonna get. And while you have the right to reject, if you do, I am gonna recommend Bobby to drop you as clients. **We are sympathetic, but we are certainly not gonna bankroll your rage.**

*Bankroll* means providing the money that someone needs for a plan, business. How can you make a figurative meaning out of this?

Comment: What is the context of the episode?

Comment: Which season and  episode is it? Do you have a link to the script?

Comment: Season 2, Episode 16. No.

Answer (score 0):

In this example I would say the intent is similar to "justify":

> We are sympathetic, but we are certainly not gonna **justify** your rage.

Or perhaps "not gonna *support*".

I would say it is kind of a figurative use of "not paying for" not necessarily meaning paying money.

Comment: Definitely "support", not "justify". It's "We're not going to use our resources to help you voice your anger about the power line company."